# Google docs - reconnect a list before the previous one

Tags: google-docs

I have two lists. A main list and a small list. The small list is nested inside the main one. We can summerize it like that :

```
1. Install process
    1. Step 1
    2. Step 2
    3. Step 3
2. Execution process
```

In google docs, I don't know how to connect the `2. Execution process` to the `1. Install process`. If I click "Continue previous numbering", it connects `2.Execution process` to the small list.

Any suggestions to finally get the same rendering as I mentioned in the example ?